# How to use `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` in a keyboard extension app

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, vibration

I am working a keyboard extension app and want to add vibration. So I add the code bellow:

```
let impact = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .soft)
impact.impactOccurred()
```

but the console print

```
2022-05-03 20:19:43.953458+0800 KeyboardWork[69583:6886602] [avas]     AVAudioSession_iOS.mm:727   Synchronous connection to media server failed. Starting asynchronous connection attempt for session 0x2836fc120.
2022-05-03 20:19:43.955750+0800 KeyboardWork[69583:6886602] [as] AudioSessionClientManager.cpp:467:ServerPort: Couldn't connect to com.apple.audio.AudioSession Error: 1100; AudioSession will not be usable
2022-05-03 20:19:43.957945+0800 KeyboardWork[69583:6886602] [hapi] CHHapticEngine.mm:1974:-[CHHapticEngine setupUnsharedAudioSessionAndReturnError:]: Failed to set category on audio session
2022-05-03 20:19:43.959841+0800 KeyboardWork[69583:6886602] [Feedback] failed initializing core haptics engine for <_UIFeedbackCoreHapticsHapticsOnlyEngine: 0x281fe8850>: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1836282486 "(null)"
2022-05-03 20:19:43.960132+0800 KeyboardWork[69583:6886600] [as] AudioSessionClientManager.cpp:467:ServerPort: Couldn't connect to com.apple.audio.AudioSession Error: 1100; AudioSession will not be usable
2022-05-03 20:19:43.964286+0800 KeyboardWork[69583:6886600] [as] AudioSessionClientManager.cpp:467:ServerPort: Couldn't connect to com.apple.audio.AudioSession Error: 1100; AudioSession will not be usable
```

and UIImpactFeedbackGenerator not work.

So How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does it work if you grant full access for the keyboard? I believe playing sounds requires that, strangely, maybe haptics too.

Comment: AudioServicesPlaySystemSound does not require full access. UIImpactFeedbackGenerato does